Best way to avoid chopped hyperlink in notification email?
Here is an interesting situation.

Here we are in the Roundcube mail reader.
We are looking at the text/plain part of this multipart MIME message.
Alas, the preview cutoff happened right in the middle of a hyperlink.
Should we

Urge fixing Roundcube? No. It is just automatically creating hyperlinks based on https strings.
Retrain the user, to instead read the text/html multipart? No. Stack Exchange sent two parts, and it is the user's choice which one to read.
Fix Stack Exchange, to be more careful to make sure the cutoff doesn't happen in the middle of a hyperlink? Maybe. But the cutoff needs to happen somewhere, and what if it happened in the middle of something else, making it mean something else: "No. <cut here> Except when Y=1." "The bad guy is Sam Nerblestein<cut>'s brother, not Sam." So it's hard to be perfect no matter how hard you try.

So perhaps users clicking on the chopped off link should just chalk it up to the 10% of the things on the Internet that don't work as expected.
That's OK for tech-savvy Stack users. But not for the general public however, or the 10% of Stack users who are not tech-savvy.

"Who to blame" Is going to get a downvote from me, particularly when presented negatively. Playing the blame game is almost never useful, and often counterproductive. On the other hand, if this was a bug report that reasonably reported the problem, giving a clear description of the issue, so it could be fixed, that would get an upvote.

Does Roundcube actually default to the text/plain view?  If a major mail client is actually showing these by default, that might motivate people to care about how they render.

That said, assuming that one does care about the text/plain version of Stack Exchange emails...is the cut-off link really even close to the worst problem in the text version of that email?  There's the misrendered quotes in the question title (rendered on-site as: Any straightened version of jogs like "ㄣ" in Unicode?), the inexplicable pound signs, the random indentation of the first line of the answer (not present in the answer's source)... It's a target-rich environment.

Interesting. https://docs.roundcube.net/doc/help/1.1/en_US/settings/preferences.html . We see that Roundcube can also turn single part HTML messages into text representations. But we are dealing with multipart. So just like we cannot say the user should have bought a desktop instead of a cellphone...

Wait, isn't that just the same chopped-off format that on-site notifications use? Because those too are absolutely breaking off inside all kinds of content. My on-site inbox also has meaningless ending "words" such as "suc…", "beca…" and "br..." right now. This looks like normal and expected behaviour. If you want the full content, shouldn't you read the full message, not the shortened version? This seems to apply equally for all kinds of content. That your mail-reader is misunderstanding this after forcing it to throw away meta-data seems not like SE's fault (there, I wrote it).

That doesn't really answer the question of what the default is, so I checked the current Roundcube source code: $config['prefer_html'] (described as "prefer displaying HTML messages") is true by default, so it seems like an out-of-the-box Roundcube installation would default to displaying HTML messages.

What is RoundCube, and why should we care about possible bug reports for it?

This isn't worth fixing in the Stack Exchange platform. Yes, it would be ideal if it didn't do that, but there is no foreseeable path to a world in which fixing this problem is the best use of a Stack developer's time.

It's 2024; approximately everyone is capable of receiving HTML email.  According to a survey from 2007, only 3% of users could only receive text email.  That was 17 years ago.  I'm sure the number is much lower now.

There are numerous more important issues impacting many more people than users of plain-text-only email.

Hypothetically, let's say that everyone decides that making the plain-text emails better is important.  There would be numerous higher priority issues than dealing with links that happen to appear right on the cutoff.  Several are visible in that screenshot:  the misrendered quotes in the question title (rendered on-site as: Any straightened version of jogs like "ㄣ" in Unicode?), the inexplicable pound signs, and the random indentation of the first line of the answer (not present in the answer's source).



About point 3 my guess is that those pound signs are deliberate and is an attempt to denote particular things as special or are trying to mark those as headings. The indentation on the first line of the answer is probably also deliberate but it fails to consider that the first paragraph of some answers might not be that long.

That is not a bug. It is by design. As also noted by MisterMiyagi. You've subscribed to emails for messages in your inbox. A message in your inbox on the site contains as viewable item:

a title to a post;
the type of content (post, comment, chat message) and a timestamp;
At most 100 characters of the content where ... as last three characters are used as an indicator that the actual content has more than 100 characters.

In the email plain/text you get exactly what you would have seen on the site in your inbox. It doesn't care whether links are chopped off in the middle, there are no more characters allowed. Allowing more characters for the email is maybe a feature to be added due to the less restricted size requirements in emails but that might not be trivial to add, assuming the message is generated real-time once and then re-used for both the on-site and email channel.
You can't avoid chopped hyperlinks, or any chopped content for that matter because the fixed limit is set at 100 characters. Adjusting that limit dynamically based on content / context is not worth the effort for your specific use case, nor any other use case I'm unaware off.

Personally I think it would be best if Stack Exchange used more care, perhaps just giving the full link instead of blindly chopping it causing an invalid link!
Or, OK. Link exceeds cutoff? Then no link is better that a sure-misfire link.

It's not clear what this answer adds beyond the question.  You've already replied "No." within the question to the two solutions that aren't this one.

Maybe you can come up with a better answer. Thanks.

An answer to what, @DanJacobson ? You've started a discussion here, yet it doesn't seem like there's anything to discuss, and you actually want to report a bug (as has been mentioned in the comments).
